# Is it possible to change text size & formatting of Numbers' formula input field?

Tags: iwork, numbers, formatting

Is it possible to set the text-size and possibly other formatting of the actual values/formula input field in Apple iWork Numbers?

Comparing these two screenshots, it seems possible to set the size of the text to something larger.

Too small text-size for my taste:

[image: Text-size too small for my taste]

Easier to read (screenshot originally posted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1983223?start=0&tstart=0)):

[image: Text-size better sized for my taste]

Comment: I'd like to know how as well. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I click in the formula entry bar I get an additional toolbar that has a "Formula Text Size" field. Does this appear on your screen?

[image]

Here's a screenshot from the [Numbers '09 User's Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Numbers09_UserGuide.pdf):

[image]

<s>I haven't found a way to make it larger than 14.</s>

### Edit

I figured out how to make it larger than 14.

1. Quit Numbers
2. Run Terminal
3. Type the following command:

`defaults write com.apple.iWork.Numbers LSFormulaBarFontSize 80`

When you run Numbers again your formula bar is plenty big:

[image: Big Big Bar]

You can use a number smaller than 80 in the Terminal command for a more reasonably-sized formula bar.

Comment: Wow. That's an astonishing answer. It's funny I didn't see that `Formula text size` dropdown menu (it's even there in my second screenshot, hehe). And the `defaults` command you provided is simply brilliant. Thank you.